# How to use DevicePolicyManagerService class

Tags: android, build

I have services_intermediates.jar that contains com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService. Using this I can compile my code (that uses DPMS) but it crashes when run on device reporting no class DevicePolicyManagerService found.

I don't want to package the whole intermediate jar with my app and so I use "provided" in gradle dependency not "compile".

On a broader perspective, how to use classes that are under /framework in AOSP but not available at runtime for use in some application package?